# Google chrome extentions java script open new tab prob

Tags: javascript, php, plugins

I'm making an extension for google chrome that allows people put player id in a field and press snap and a new tab will be opened with the url the text that user typed.

Any idea what js codes should I use for  the url text in new tab?

Edit:
What I did:

I used php instead of js

I used `$_Post["name"]` but there is problem too!

I need the var to appear only like the person typed it... not with `key=var`

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: add your effort in the question by editing, don't post code in comment.

Comment: Please, don't comment and the code in the question by [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32959819/edit)

Comment: oh sorry about that .. but did you got my problem ? :)

Comment: I am a reviewer of your question. I have no specific knowledge in this sector. Thanks.

Comment: Please, remove your comments and add your effort in the question, otherwise the question is not a good one. Thanks.